# How to parse boolean with config parser

Tags: python, ini, configparser

Using python's builtin `configparser`, I want to parse boolean values in my conf file.

Example:

```
[SECTION]
foo = False
```

However, when accessing the variable I notice that it is processed as a string.

```
>>> config['SECTION']['foo']
'False'
```

Furthermore, when I attempt to correct this behavior and reassign key `foo` to it's proper boolean representative, I get this error

```
>>>         if config['SECTION']['foo'] == 'True':
...             config['SECTION']['foo'] = True
...         elif config['SECTION']['foo'] == 'False':                                                                                                                                      
...             config['SECTION']['foo'] = False
...         else:                                    
...             Exception("foo must be bool")
TypeError: option values must be strings
```

Unfortunately, this behavior leads to problematic situations where the following performs unexpectedly

```
print(config['SECTION']['foo']) # 'False'

if config['SECTION']['foo']:
   print('do things when foo is True') # this runs, but foo actually 
                                       # represents false, but in string form
```

How am I supposed to deal with booleans when parsing with `configparser` with the least amount of overhead as possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `getboolean`, a function on the section object.

For example

```
>>> config['SECTION'].getboolean('foo')
False
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.getboolean)